# Need code for validating existing data and creating new rows with push of button

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to coding VBA development. I'm trying to have button in the Summary workbook that takes dates from an input file and puts it in a summary file. But I need to validate the project number because the order is not always the same and new lines may be added. And if any lines in the input file that are not in the summary file it will add it and highlight red. Example.

(Input File.xlsx)

Project No.: ___Location:____Project Description:___Start   ____End
300 __________DET _______Electrical ___________09/04/16  __09/08/16
405 __________ATL _______ Basement __________  04/01/14 __03/31/15
408 __________ATL ________Walls ______________03/02/15__09/25/15
414 __________ATL ________Plumbing ___________04/01/14 _03/31/15
400 __________PHL _______Sewage ___________   09/01/16 __10/10/17

(Summary File.xlsm)

Project No.: _Location: __ Project Description:___  Start____End
408 ________ATL _______Walls ____________00/00/00 __00/00/00
405 ________ATL _______Basement ________00/00/00 __00/00/00
414 ________ATL _______Plumbing _________00/00/00 __00/00/00

** "Push Button in Summary File.xlsm" **

Summary File.xlsm now looks like:

Project No.: ________Location: ____Project Description: ____Start ______End
408 ________________ATL ________Walls _______________03/02/15 ___09/25/15
405 ________________ATL ________Basement ___________04/01/14 ___03/31/15
414 ________________ATL ________Plumbing ____________04/01/14 ___03/31/15
300"Highlight Red" ____DET _______Electrical ____________09/04/16 ___09/08/16
400"Highlight Red" ____PHL _______Sewage _____________09/01/16 ___10/10/17

Any code examples/help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Compare(): Dim win As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, s As Long, PNo As String, K, n As Long
Set win = Workbooks("InputFile.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws = Workbooks("SummaryFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
s = win.Range("A:A").Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
For i = 2 To s: PNo = Trim(win.Range("A" & i))
.Item(PNo) = i: Next i: K = .Keys()

s = ws.Range("A:A").Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row + 1
For n = LBound(K) To UBound(K)
For i = 2 To UBound(K) + 1: PNo = Trim(ws.Range("A" & i))
If K(n) = PNo Then
ws.Range("D" & i).Resize(1, 2).Value = _
win.Range("D" & .Item(K(n))).Resize(1, 2).Value
GoTo GetNext: End If: Next i

ws.Range("A" & s).Resize(1, 5).Value = _
win.Range("A" & .Item(K(n))).Resize(1, 5).Value
ws.Range("A" & s).Resize(1, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
s = s + 1
GetNext: Next n
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Do you **have** to create a new file called "Summary File" with new lines? What about duplicating "Input File", and comparing to the Summary File without the new lines? You can easily use a Conditional Formatting rule to highlight rows in "Input File" that aren't in "Summary File".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, thank you for posting your first question. To attract the best possible answers, the asked question should be clear about what you are trying to achieve. It should describe what you have done to get to where you are now. There is a [great article about how to write good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please consider reading it and editing your question to be clearer about what you want. **Please post the code you've written, so far.***